# how to set tab focus on li page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have below code in html.

```
<li class="selected" runat="server" id="lihome"><a href="/ISS/home.aspx" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

Now I want to start my tabbing from this li when my page get loaded. Please suggest how to do this.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should focus the anchor element inside the "selected" LI, since only form elements, anchors and iframes are *focusable*:

```
$(function () { 
  $('li.selected a').focus(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () { 
  $('#lihome a').focus(); 
});
```