# jquery ui tabs from xml in dialog - focus issue (not active tabs will not take focus from "tab")

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

Ok,

posting code will be tricky, but I will try to update tomorrow with an example.

My dialog is dynamic and loaded with dynamic content, including dynamic jquery ui tabs. When I tab through the dialog, the focus stops at the first tab and does not proceed to the next tab. I have tried to set the focus to the next `li a` I have tried to blur the active tab on `keycode.tab`, and have added differing `tabindex's` to the tabs - among other things.

I did pull the tabs out of the dialog, and the tabs focus correctly as I tab through using the keyboard. I'm assuming it's some type of issue with the dialog and then tabs being loaded through json.

using jQuery 1.4.2

using jQuery UI 1.8.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this thread: [how to set tab focus on li page load using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648203/how-to-set-tab-focus-on-li-page-load-using-jquery)

Could it be that you're trying to set focus to a DOM element that can't receive focus?

Comment: I'm not even trying to set the focus on the first li, the issue is that as I tab through the content in my dialog, once it gets to the first tab it sticks. It will go the first anchor in the first tab, but won't proceed to any other tab. I've gone through all of the code, and removed any events/functions acting on the tabs, but it still won't tab to the next tab. It's driving me crazy.